# Exim4 Smart Host Relay

Tags: smtp, exim, smarthost

I am running Exim 4.71. I want to:

1. Route all email *from* A.com through mail.A.com
2. Route all email *from* [B-E].com through mail.B.com
3. Send all other email directly.

Here is the configuration I have that doesn't work like I hoped:

```
domainlist a_domains = a.com
domainlist b_domains = b.com : c.com : d.com : e.com

begin routers

smart_route_a:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = +a_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = +a_domains mail.a.com
  no_more

smart_route_b:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = +b_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = +b_domains mail.mollenhour.com
  no_more

dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
  no_more
```

When I send an email e.g. with PHP's `mail(`) or `Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp` setting both From: and Return-Path: as user@a.com, the `smart_route_a` router is not used, the dnslookup is used instead. Disabling dnslookup results in no mail being sent.

From the logs it appears that email sent *to* someone@a.com uses `smart_route_a`, but the same email sent from user@a.com to user@gmail.com is sent using `dnslookup`.

How do I make email *from* user@a.com be relayed via mail.a.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional like

```
route_list = * "${if match{$header_from:}{\N.*\.a\.com$\N} {mail.a.com}}"
```

domains = only checks the destination domain not the source domain.